# Storing JsonWebToken in frontend

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

So, I'm right now learning Node.js and I have few newbies doubts. I tried to search here and also in Google and I couldn't find my answer. I'm doing a Jwt Authentication and sending the token through header to my frontend which I'm rendering using handlebars as a view engine, my question is, how can I store that token and sending back through headers in every request? and What's the best way to do it?

Comment: I'm storing jwt token in brower's local storage at my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on chosen token expiration policy, you can choose different options. As previously said, token may be of course stored in localStorage.

The more secure option is keeping the token in memory. I would strongly suggest using short-lived JWTs and require them to be re-issued regularly (e.g. via an OAuth2 [refresh token flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)).